# ASP.NET A question about safety after writing some data to HtmlControl

Tags: asp.net, thread-safety

I have a hidden input on my form, and my JavaScript code writes there dynamically generated string based on the user behavior on the page.

Later, I access to that inpput via server side code.

**Many users will be using this page at the same time**, so what about thread safety ?

I mean, could it be possible that userA has an access to that string generated by userB ? Or maybe server will read that string from each user's Web Browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all happening at the client side, on each individual user's machine - when they post the data from their machine, you'll get the data created there - there will be no cross pollution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, there won't be any problem regarding thread safety.

Considering the Server side, when a user visits an asp.net website, he/she is given a different application domain in the server, so I guess there won't be much trouble here.

And about the javascript, it is executing inside the client's browser and machine, so why on earth there will be concurrency problem?